# Country Vowel Filter Function

Tags: javascript, filter

I am having a great deal of difficult trying to create a javascript function that will filter the names off all countries and return the countries that start with a vowel.

This is what I have so far:

```
var countries = ["Lithuania", "Congo", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Gabon", "United Arab Emirates", "Turkey", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Hungary", "France Metropolitan", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Singapore", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Cyprus", "Rwanda", "Somalia", "Chile", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Uzbekistan", "Ghana", "Bahamas", "Austria", "Monaco", "Iceland", "Tajikistan", "Estonia", "France", "Central African Republic", "Martinique", "Mongolia", "Brunei Darussalam", "French Guiana", "Cape Verde", "Comoros", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Antigua and Barbuda", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Bouvet Island", "Maldives", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Jordan", "Bhutan", "Finland", "Luxembourg", "Vanuatu", "Uganda", "Thailand", "Liberia", "Ethiopia", "Suriname", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Niger", "Burkina Faso", "Italy", "Indonesia", "Nepal", "Mauritania", "Cameroon", "Fiji", "Solomon Islands", "Ireland", "Philippines", "Tuvalu", "Sudan", "Guadeloupe", "Venezuela", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Samoa", "Niue", "Papua New Guinea", "Hong Kong", "Burundi", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Uruguay", "Vietnam", "Oman", "Christmas Island", "Israel", "Montserrat", "Czech Republic", "Senegal", "Afghanistan", "Greenland", "Norway", "Eritrea", "Haiti", "Tunisia", "Swaziland", "Guinea-Bissau", "Botswana", "Greece", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Netherlands", "Jamaica", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Ecuador", "Morocco", "Grenada", "Poland", "Malaysia", "Mauritius", "Gambia", "Zimbabwe", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Malawi", "Puerto Rico", "United States", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Azerbaijan", "Cook Islands", "Cayman Islands", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Korea, Republic of", "Costa Rica", "Dominica", "Slovenia", "Australia", "Peru", "Albania", "Palau", "Netherlands Antilles", "Saudi Arabia", "Canada", "Moldova, Republic of", "Faroe Islands", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Andorra", "Nicaragua", "Panama", "Tokelau", "South Africa", "Lesotho", "French Southern Territories", "Algeria", "Guinea", "Aruba", "Saint Lucia", "Togo", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Yugoslavia", "Liechtenstein", "Latvia", "Kyrgyzstan", "Cuba", "Zambia", "Marshall Islands", "Mozambique", "Sierra Leon"];

function CountryFilter(input) {
  for (i=0; i<=input.length; i++) {
    if (input.charAt(0) === "a","e","i","o","u") {
      return input;
    }
  }
}

document.write(CountryFilter(countries));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startsWithVowels = countries.filter(function(country) {
  var firstLetter = country.charAt(0);
  return firstLetter.match(/[aeiou]/i); // or firstLetter.match([AEIOU])
});

console.log(startsWithVowels);
```

`/` - marks the start of the regular expression

`[aeiou]` - Matches if the character is `a` or `e` or `i` or `o` or `u`

`/` - marks the end of the regular expression

`i` - flag which allows case insensitivity.

The `i` flag is not needed in your case, as every country's first character is capitalized, but you ever know what data you might encounter. It is better not to make assumptions about the data.)

Play with the code [here](https://repl.it/F3x3)

For more info on regular expressions, read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: That for sure does the job, but could you explain it a bit? OP probably doesn't know about `.filter()` and RegExp.

Comment: @yuriy636 Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just joined this site. I am amazed at how fast I was able to receive help!

Comment: when was "country" defined?

Comment: @csagar  Aha! You need to read the documentation of the `filter` function. Have a look at it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Simply put, the `filter` method passes every element in the array to the callback function and if the function returns `true` , the element will be added to a new array. This will happen for every element in the array and the element will be accessible to the callback function as the first argument. Hope it helps!